# x86 label in data section

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to write simple `vtable` for my own compiler. I want to create table in `.DATA` section which contains proper function labels.

I have this piece of code:

```
.data
vtable1:
  .word f1
vtable2:
  .word f2
.global f1
// F1 code here
.global f2
// F2 code here
```

Anyway I'm getting error: relocation truncated to fit: `R_386_16` against symbol 'f2' defined in `.data` section in `/tmp/ccOFQaDv.o`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want `.int` not `.word` which is 16 bits only.